# Python program to output the smallest palindromic number above a given input

Tags: python

I am quite new to python. I want to create a Python program to output the smallest palindromic number above a given input. But this input can be up to 20 digits. I tried finding all the palindromic numbers and adding them to a list. But it seems like for 20 digit numbers, it is a very long process. What python code would work? Secondly, I needed to find the largest difference between a palindromic number (of up to 20 digits) and then the next highest palindromic numbers. Finally, I had to find how many integers between 1 and 99999 are not the sum of 2 palindromic numbers. It seems to be a difficult task without storing all the palindromic numbers first.

Comment: If you can rephrase your question to ask about an algorithm, it might be on-topic here.  Coding questions and questions asking how to do something in Python are off-topic here.  Also, please tell us the context where you encountered this task.  Can you link to it or provide a reference?  Is it a contest or online problem?  If this is in a class, what concept have you been learning recently?

Comment: You can find any palindromic number by taking some number, reversing it, and concatenating the two numbers (and, for an odd-length number, adding an arbitrary digit in the middle). You can use this property to solve the 20-digit tasks. For the task with 99999, note that there are only ~$10^3$ palindromes below 10000. Computing all ~$10^6$ possible sums is easily doable.